# Selenium iOS Driver

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, ios, selenium

I took a clone of the [Selenium iOS Driver](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/IPhoneDriver) however xcode isn't allowing me to build for a device.

Here is the menu:

[image]

When I select 'device' from the list, it pauses for a second then appears to do nothing.

NB: Im using, xcode Version 3.2.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to target settings (Project->Edit Active Target) and set Base SDK to Latest iOS. Maybe you should also change this in project settings too.